# Java Prepared Statement not working with my loop

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement

I am new to this and trying to add some dates into a Oracle database using prepared statements. this is my code:

```
CODE REMOVED, code updated.
```

This produces the following:

```
INSERT into TEST_RESULTS12233 (DB_ID, DATED1, DATED2, DATED3, DATED4) values (t1_seq.nextval, to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24.mi'), to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24.mi'), to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24.mi'), to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24.mi'))
Event1
Event2
Event3
Event4
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10500)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:230)
at sandpit.testsand.main(testsand.java:85)
```

If i replace pstatement in setString with Event1, the batch executes.
Does anyone know how I can get this to work??
Thanks

Here is the full code as requested:

```
     //MORE CODE AS REQUESTED 


     String inserttotable = "INSERT into TEST_RESULTS12233 (DB_ID";
     String stateclose = ")";
     String insertvalues =(" values (t1_seq.nextval");
     StringBuilder insertBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     StringBuilder valueBuilder = new StringBuilder();
     int timestoloop = 4;

     for (i=1; i<=timestoloop; i++)

     {           
         insertBuilder.append(", DATED"+i);
         valueBuilder.append(", to_date(?, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24.mi')");

     }

     String finalinsert = inserttotable + insertBuilder.toString()+ stateclose;
     String finalvalues = insertvalues + valueBuilder.toString() + stateclose;
     String insertsql = finalinsert + finalvalues;
     System.out.println(insertsql);
     String insertresults = insertsql;

        PreparedStatement prepState = conn.prepareStatement(insertresults);


    String Event1 = "22122014 13.26";
    String Event2 = "22122014 13.27";
    String Event3 = "22122014 13.28";
    String Event4 = "22122014 13.29"; 


     for (i=1; i<=timestoloop; i++)

     {           
        String pstatement = "Event"+i;
        System.out.println(pstatement);
        prepState.setString(i, pstatement);


     }

     prepState.addBatch();
     prepState.executeBatch();
```

Comment: Please share some more code about the table structure and prepared statements and query.

Comment: If you want to set a date in a database, then you should create a Timestamp and use setTimestamp(), not setString(). setString() is for setting... strings.

Comment: Using `setString(1, "Event1")` is not the same as `setString(1, Event1)`...

Comment: So how can I use Event1 instead of hardcoding Event1 into my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a mess by creating the variable name dynamically by appending the counter as a `String` literal (`Event1`) and setting them to the prepared statement as a `String` input. You are actually setting the `String` literals like (`Event1`) instead of Values (`22122014 13.26`). This is not the way you should do.You may have to set the values directly like

```
 prepState.setString(1, Event1);
 prepState.setString(2, Event2);
 prepState.setString(3, Event3);
 prepState.setString(4, Event4);
```

I'd suggest you to go for a List of String literals having all the Event values. Iterate them and set them in the Prepared statement and execute the query.

```
List<String> eventValues = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Is it not equivalent to the loop that OP is used?

Comment: @Braj: no. Event1 is a variable whose value is "22122014 13.26". pStatement is a variable whose value is "Event1".

Comment: No, it is not. the loop is having a serious bug. OP creates `Event1`,`Event2` etc. and sets it to the prepared statement instead of values like `22122014 13.29`

Comment: Erm, I have dynamically changing values, sometimes I have 10 rows to insert to, sometimes 100. So this will not work for me.

Comment: @user3588388 if you sometimes have 10 values and sometimes 100, then it means you have an array or list of values. Then loop over the array or list, and insert each value in the list. What your code tries to insert is the name of a variable. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @user3588388 You should put prepState.addBatch(); into the for loop

Comment: How can I use this list array with code. I need the List to be in the loop. I still get the error using the following code:

Comment: I still get the error using the following code:    'List<String> eventValues = new ArrayList<String>();
      eventValues.add("Event"+i);
      String pstatement = eventValues.get(0);'

Answer (score 0):

I believe you mentioned you already tried an arraylist but it should look something like this:

```
List<String> events=new ArrayList<String>();
    events.add("22122014 13.26");
    events.add("22122014 13.27");
    events.add("22122014 13.28");
    events.add("22122014 13.29");


     for (i=1; i<=timestoloop; i++)

     {           
        String pstatement = "Event"+i;
        System.out.println(pstatement);
        prepState.setString(i, events.get(i));
        prepState.addBatch();
     }
```

You were using the string "Event1" from your variable rather than the actual variable. 
prepState.setString(i,"event"+i) does not equal prepState.setString(i,event1).  One simply returns a string one is simply a variable holding the string value, the latter being the one you want.